# Where do deleted files from Apache Netbeans go?

Tags: java, file, netbeans, delete-file, delete-directory

I accidently deleted source folder from my Netbeans Project , but when I try **History->Revert Deleted** nothing shows . Also I checked Recycle Bin and also the hidden Recycle bin on D: Recovery Drive but still the same Result . I tried to deleted on purpose other object from the same project , but they still disappear without any trace .  The **/path/to/folder/NetbeansProject** directory is also effected by the delete on my IDE so no trace of my src folder. As last resort I tried Recuva but nothing there .
So my question is where do the deleted files from Netbeans IDE go ?

Comment: Believe it or not, they are deleted. They go nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask Netbeans to delete a file, you get a confirmation dialog. After approving the file is deleted, as Federico mentioned.

The menu item "History->Revert Deleted" refers to version control. If you use version control regularly you indeed can go back in time and retrieve the files. However if you create a file, then delete it before it ever was sent to version control there is no chance.